# communication between 2 coldfusion applications

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have 2 different application

one for backend and one for frontend

now if the admin/manager changes something in backend I have no possibility at front end realize these changes.

Is there a way available like a Gateway or Communication system which may exchange information between 2 applications?

Comment: Please provide more details of front and back ends.

Comment: Are you using same Database for two applications ?

Comment: Yes, I am using same database

Answer (score 0):

It is generally poor design to couple independent applications. In fact, one of the key heuristics of software design is *separation of concerns*. Another is *information hiding*. These heuristics remind us to avoid superfluous communication between different parts of an application or between different applications.

I would therefore advise you against building such a *gateway* or *communication system*. Unless it is an integral part of one of the applications or of both of them. There are other possible solutions.

Both applications are apparently yours. So, a possible solution is to store the code of both applications - including appropriate comments in the code - in a version-control system such as Git or SVN. You will then be informed instantly whenever there is a change. Also, you will have access to information about previous changes.

It could, on the other hand, be necessary for the backend to have the responsibility of supplying the frontend with information. Then this should be included as an integral part of the backend's functionality and design.

For example, in web applications, the backend may contain an updates page. The contents of the page are updated to reflect changes. Also, access to the page is restricted to users with special permissions.